# Strange behaviour when converting string to UTF-8 character

Tags: java, utf-8

I have datatype stored as blob (XML) in Oracle DB.
I am retrieving this column and converting to byte[] and then to string. I do some string operations and converting it to UTF-8 format and inserting back into the DB. Some special characters are inserted as junk characters. I do not really know what I am doing wrong? 
Any idea/ help would be highly appreciated.

Here is the source code.

```
     // DB COnnection
     // Get the resultset

     Blob data = (Blob) rs.getBlob(3);
 byte[] bdata = data.getBytes(1,(int)data.length());  

 // Converting to String and doing operation
 s = new String(bdata);   
 // String operation


 // Before inserting into DB, converting to UTF-8 format.
 byte[] dataAsByteArray = s.getBytes("UTF8");  
 updateStmt.setBinaryStream(1,
          new  ByteArrayInputStream(dataAsByteArray),dataAsByteArray.length);

 commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the BLOB initially in UTF-8 format ? If it's *really* in XML, I would use the XML APIs to read and interpret the header. The header (if present) may specify the character encoding. See [DocumentBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html), and read the BLOB as an InputStream to avoid any byte-to-char conversions on your side.

Note in the above, when you convert it to a String, you don't specify the byte-to-char encoding there.

```
 // Converting to String and doing operation
 s = new String(bdata);
```

The above uses the default charset that the JVM is running with (doc [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[]%29)). So I think there's some possibility for error in the above. I would confirm the character encoding of the BLOB, and enforce the byte-to-char encoding in the String conversion.

Additionally, I can't remember if `UTF8` is valid in addition to `UTF-8` for specifying an encoding. I guess it may be since I'd expect an exception otherwise, but perhaps worth checking.

Comment: You are right. I should use XML API to read and interpret the header.

I am using Javolution library and it has class called UTF8StreamReader. 

I thought of populating some dummy/fake data for testing purpose using the above code in a faster way but it seems I have to stick with original way :)

Comment: @Brian Agnew - canonical names for Sun Java 6 encodings are listed here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html